# How to fill NAs in a given column of a subset of the original dataframe with the average of that column based on two other variables

Tags: r

So I have a student dataset that I am currently cleaning and I've taken a subset of the dataframe and want to fill the NAs in the salary column of this subset based on the average salary associated with a particular major and the number of internships for non missing values obviously.

so if I had:

```
subset(work_dat, (is.na(Employed) & outcome_table=="Employed - Full-time"), select=major, int_numb, salary)

 Major     Int_numb      salary
 <fctr>      <dbl>           <dbl>
 Biochem       2              NA                
 Biosystems    2              NA
```

I want to substitute the average salary for biochem and biosystems majors, for example, with in this case 2 internships into the NA values for salary.

```
 Major     Int_numb      avg_salary
 <fctr>      <dbl>           <dbl>
 Biochem       2              70000             
 Biosystems    2              290000
```

Comment: Also, I dont want to rename the column to avg_salary, I was just showing as apart of my example those are the average salaries for individuals with 2 internships with either of those degrees and I want the average salaries to replace the NAs in my original subsetted data.

Comment: It helps if you have a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking for help, as we can't help you if we can't run the same code as you. Plus, I'd recommend learning about [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/), as it makes it easier to make a MWE.

Comment: Just FYI I removed the tags rstudio and r-markdown, since you're referring to neither

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` for this.
Something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
work_dat %>%
    group_by(Major) %>%
    mutate(avg_salary = ifelse(is.na(avg_salary), mean(avg_salary, na.rm = T), avg_salary))
```

Comment: I don't want to change the entire column just that specific subsetted portion of the column.  I think your could would alter the entire salary column and also it doesn't take into account the internship number column (int_numb)